# Performance Point Data Source

Tags: performance, sharepoint, performancepoint

Working in Performance Point 2010, trying to get the data source connected to a new Scorecard. Ive created a data source from my SSAS cube and I can create a scorecard, but I want to be able to place dimensions (on the right of Dashboard Designer) and drag them into the workspace. Problem is it doesn't show any dimensions from the cube although I know they are in there. Anyone ever had this issue before?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the screenshot, it looks like a data source needs to be selected. If the data source is not listed when you first add it to the workspace, you will need to save the workspace before you are able to use the data source in filters, scorecards etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the datasource has been created, but not actually added to the cube. Go back to the SSAS cube in visual studio and open the Cube Structure window and make sure the dimensions are included [image]

Also note that Dashboard Designer needs to be closed and re-opened in order to pick up and structural changes in the SSAS Cube (some sort of dumb caching issue).